# How to create persistent SSH connection between two servers in systemctl

Tags: linux, ssh, proxy, tunnel, forwarding

This is my `/etc/systemd/system/proxy.service` file:

```
[Unit]
Description=proxy
After=system.slice multi-user.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=root

StandardOutput=stdout
StandardError=stderr
SyslogIdentifier=root

ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /root/proxy/proxy.sh
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I run `systemctl status proxy`, I see it's not running and I see this error in my website:

```
An error occurred: Failed to connect to api.domain.com port 9999: Connection refused
```

But if I manually run `/root/proxy/proxy.sh` in my terminal, connection to `api.domain.com:9999` is persistent and works fine.
This is `systemctl status proxy`:

```
● proxy.service - proxy
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/proxy.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead) since Sat 2022-01-22 17:02:40 +0330; 5min ago
  Process: 1830 ExecStart=/usr/bin/bash /root/proxy/proxy.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: IPv4 address for veth-srv-proxy:  192.0.2.2
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: IPv4 address for wg0:             10.7.0.1
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: * Super-optimized for small spaces - read how we shrank the memory
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: footprint of MicroK8s to make it the smallest full K8s around.
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: https://ubuntu.com/blog/microk8s-memory-optimisation
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: 5 updates can be applied immediately.
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: 5 of these updates are standard security updates.
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com root[1830]: *** System restart required ***
Jan 22 17:02:40 server.domain.com systemd[1]: Started proxy.
```

I see it's exited with SUCCESS (in server login), but in human's logic it's not working.

What should I do to keep persistent connection?

I should mention that I tried [this](https://confluence.jaytaala.com/display/TKB/Create+a+persistent+SSH+tunnel+between+servers+with+systemd) link and [this](https://www.brandonchecketts.com/archives/creating-a-permanent-ssh-tunnel-between-linux-servers) in my command, but it does not work to keep it persistent.

**Update 1**

The contents of `/root/proxy/proxy.sh`:

```
ssh -L 127.0.0.1:9999:api.domain.com:443 remote-server
```

Comment: What does your script contain? (Does it actually match the expectations systemd has for Type=forking?)

Comment: @user1686 I edited the question and added contents of `proxy.sh`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, a basic `ssh` will by default start an interactive shell session. Once that shell reaches "end of file" (when no more input can be read from stdin) it will exit. As services have *no* input available to them, the interactive shell will just exit immediately.

For a service, the `ssh -N` option would be more appropriate: it doesn't try to start any shell session, nor a batch command, it creates a connection that's used purely for the tunnels.

Second, `Type=forking` has the expectation that the program in question will "daemonize" or "go into background". If it doesn't do that – e.g. you run it from terminal and it continues occupying that terminal – then it is not Type=forking, it's just Type=simple/Type=exec.

(Systemd doesn't care whether the service will use fork() in general; Type= is specifically about whether the initial process will fork *and exit* i.e. "daemonize" during startup.)

With ssh, the `ssh -f` option (that is, `ssh -fN` in this case) would make it Type=forking. Without the `-f` it would be Type=simple/exec in your case (though it may also be Type=oneshot in situations when it's given a short-running command).

(Though the intermediate `bash` process might muddle things up a bit. It's unnecessary if all you want is to run 1 command anyway – just put that command directly in the systemd service.)

With everything put together:

- I would prefer using the 'forking' mode, as it allows systemd to clearly distinguish a service that's still "starting" from one that is fully "started".

  ```
  [Service]
  Type=forking
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -f -N -L 127.0.0.1:9999:api.domain.com:443 remote-server
  ```
- But in some cases 'simple' will work well enough:

  ```
  [Service]
  Type=simple
  ExecStart=/usr/bin/ssh -N -L 127.0.0.1:9999:api.domain.com:443 remote-server
  ```

Comment: Thanks my friend:) It's working now with both `simple` and `forking` mode

Comment: There's another question. What if I want to add another `-L localhost:9990:api2.domain2.com:443 remote-server`? Should I create a new `systemd` service? Or I can add another line to my `proxy.sh` file?

Comment: You can just have multiple `-L` options in the same command?